# How to push new date to array with no time?

Tags: javascript

Trying the following but I get minutes too while I only need day/month/year (in this order)

```
      for (s = 0; s<dataSetCopy.length; s++) {
        newdataSetCopy.push(new Date(dataSetCopy[s]));
      }

      console.log(newdataSetCopy);
```

`dataSetCopy` array has dates like `3/02/20` and I need it to convert it to `3/02/2020`

Full code I am trying:

```
      let dataSetCopy=[];
      let newdataSetCopy=[];
      initialDataSet.forEach(ds=>{
        ds.data.forEach( obj=>{
          dataSetCopy.push(obj.date)
        })
      })
      dataSetCopy.sort((a,b)=> Date.parse(a)-Date.parse(b));

      for (s = 0; s<dataSetCopy.length; s++) {
        newdataSetCopy.push(new Date(dataSetCopy[s]));
      }

      console.log(newdataSetCopy);
```

Comment: why down votes?

Comment: Your `newdataSetCopy` array contains Date objects, not strings. Consider making an attempt to fix the format where you turn the objects into strings later.

Comment: You should use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for the best parsing. JavaScript dates are terrible, especially if you have to deal with multiple time zones. It is usually better to track dates as strings when they have to go through many layers (browser, apis, databases), but you can decide that after playing around with moment.

Comment: @ps2goat Simply formatting a year from a date is trivial, no need for a big library for something like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes indeed but I first tried to convert those dates to full year but I was not lucky so I tried to re create the date, is there any easier way? Only need to convert the date I have with full year and not with 2 digits only

Comment: Maybe not, but I enjoy using moment more than using the js date object.

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated with full code I am trying

Comment: @ps2goat trying moment but how would I apply it to each object in array ?

Comment: @ps2goat ok got it working by doing `dataSetCopy.push(moment().calendar(obj.date));` but I sometimes get the day as a string and time when I push `40: "03/09/2020"
41: "Monday at 3:48 AM"
42: "Monday at 3:48 AM"
43: "Monday at 3:48 AM"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (s = 0; s<dataSetCopy.length; s++) {
    let current_datetime = new Date(dataSetCopy[s]);
    let formattedDate = current_datetime.getDate() + "/" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + current_datetime.getFullYear();
    newdataSetCopy.push(formattedDate);
}

console.log(newdataSetCopy);
```

Comment: do we still do this date parse now to sort? newdataSetCopy.sort((a,b)=> Date.parse(a)-Date.parse(b));